# Creating BIG spatio-temporal time series data in R

Tags: r, database

I want to create a time series daily dataframe (from 1 Jan 2006 to 31 dec 2018 - 4749 rows) at 255 different locations from the study area. So the desired table (as shown below, Table 1) should have repeated rows of dates from 1Jan2006 to 31dec2018 (Total: 1210995 rows) at 255 unique locations. I later want to join this new table with another data (as shown below, Table 2) which has daily temperature values populated in 255 columns for each location. Here is how my data should look like:

Table 1
[Table 1 Desired final time series table representing dates as chunks at 255 different locations with temp variable as a new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2yW2.png)

(

**Date       Location    Temp Value  Chunk_id**
1/1/2006   Location1   29.6oC        1
.          Location1   ..            1
.          Location1   ..            1
.          ..          ..            1
1/31/2018  ..          ..            1
1/1/2006   Location2   32.1oC        2
.          Location2   31.1oC        2
.          Location2   ..            2
1/31/2018 ...         ..             2
)

Here is the data that I have and want to transform

Table 2

[Table 2 Daily Temperature data at various locations given in different fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygq5q.png)

(
Date         Location 1     Location2 ....... Location255
1/1/2006     29.6oC         32.1oC            31.1oC
1/2/2006     32.0oC         33.1oC            32.5oC
1/3/2006     35.6oC         34.1oC            34.2oC
.            .              .                 .
.            .              .                 .
.            .              .                 .
1/1/2007     .              .                 .
1/2/2007     .              .                 .
1/3/2007     .              .                 .
)

Please note that I am still struggling with R, so a comprehensive answer will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I came up with that should transform the shape of your data from the format you have to the format you want. One thing you have to further clarify is where the 'Chunk_ID' column comes from.

As you can see below I use the data.table and string packages.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dt <- data.table(Date = c('2006.01.01', '2006.01.02'), 
                 location1 = c(22.2, 24.6),
                 location2 = c(22.5, 24.7))

melted <- melt(dt, id.vars = c('Date')) 

melted[,`:=`(variable = str_sub(variable, 9, 9))]

setnames(melted, c("variable","value"), c("Location","Temperature_values"))
```

If you want some description in addition to the code let me know.

Edit: Additional Description.

Thank you for providing info on the chunk_id column. I don't see why it would be necessary. Based on the example you provided it seems to contain the same values as the location column.

First of all I would really recommend using the datatable package since it is very fast and secondly it has a very concise syntax.
Suppose you have a csv file you would simply import it this way (make sure you are in the right directory or include the complete/absolute filename):

```
df <- fread('your_file.csv')
```

The next step is simply to reshape the data from the wide format to long format. This is done by the `melt` function of datatable and is the key step in transforming your data. As you can see, the id column (named id.vars) is your 'Date' column.
Next is to extract the number of each location. In the original df the columns are named 'location1', 'location2', etc. In the final df I only saw the number of each location, hence we extract the last character with the `strings_sub` function from the package stringr.
And lastly we would just rename the columns with the `setnames` function from datatable. First you have the old columnnames, and next to it the new column names. That means the 'variable' column gets renamed to 'Location'.

Let me know if you are now able to transform your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Yes can you please provide some more description.While I was trying to figure out the solution, somebody else mentioned using chunk_ids to assort location data with respect to dates.

Comment: It has worked wondrously, it was a big step in my data management that I wasn't able to figure out. Thank you so much.